# Laptop fast but gets suddenly slow

Tags: windows-10

When I first start my laptop, it's decently fast, but at one point, it suddenly gets a dramatic cut in speed. Nothing loads fast, sound is incredibly choppy and it's a pain to use. Sometimes, it'll return to normal. I have a tab with some music pinned, and it runs great for ~2-3 minutes. I'm running Win10, and I've had the laptop since late last July. Speccy: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/lNMiz0XfhE4pz4IW1i0OvHE

Some stuff I've tried:

Malwarebytes (all types of scan)

ESET scan

AdwCleaner scan

Clean booting

Chkdsk

Cleared up free space

Defragging drive

System file checker

---

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: `and it runs great for ~2-3 minutes` - And what do you do in these 2-3 minutes? For all we can assume, it's possible you are opening 128 Youtube-tabs in Firefox at the same time, resulting in 100% usage of both RAM and CPU. But seriously: what processes are running, and what does Task Manager say about the CPU/RAM/HDD-usage before/when the issue occurs?

Comment: I got some screenshots. Sorry for them being out of order: https://imgur.com/a/kHZzQ

Comment: What's in the startupsection? Can you look at the processes-tab and make a screenshot of the most CPU-and HDD-demanding processes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your disk was at 100%. I had a similar problem in Windows 10 with the Superfetch service (seems it tries to improve performance, but overloads the disk).

I disabled this service and everything is now responsive:

Start -> Run -> services.msc

Find superfetch, double-click and select Startup type -> Disabled

Although I would run an error check on the disk to be safe as it might be failing.